# Show that $g(x)=\sqrt{x^{2}+4}$ is continuous at $x=1$

Tags: continuity

Let $g(x)=\sqrt{x^{2}+4}$ from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I want to show that $g$ is continuous at $x=1$.

I have to show that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-1|< \delta \implies |g(x)-g(1)|<\epsilon$.

So I do some rough work first and start with $$|g(x)-g(1)|$$ $$=|\sqrt{x^{2}+4} -\sqrt{5}|$$ $$\leq|\sqrt{x^{2}+4}| + |\sqrt{5}|$$.

I am stuck on what to do after. The plan is to choose the right $\delta$.

Comment: Should there be something between your lines? Maybe equal or inequal signs?

Comment: @Ive added the equal signs.

Comment: How about if you multiply top and bottom by conjugate  $\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{5}$? That creates an $x^2-1$ in the numerator which is factorable. That could be handy since the "delta" part contains an $x-1$. Just a funny thought.

Comment: The last one is not true at all. Those two things are not equal.

Comment: @avid19 Doesn't it hold by the absolute-value properties: $|-a|=|a|$ and $|a+b|=|a|+|b|$?

Comment: That second equality is patently false. For example, let $a=-b=1$ then you are claiming that $|1-1|=|1|+|-1|$, or that $0=2$.

Comment: @avid19 Yes, you're right. Should have an inequality in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in a comment of imranfat, multiply by the conjugate, i.e.
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x^2+4}-\sqrt{5}=\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+4}-\sqrt{5})(\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{5})}{\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{5}}=\frac{x^2-1}{\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{5}}=\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{5}}.
\end{align*}
Now, if $|x-1|<\delta$, then $|x+1|=|x-1+2|\leq|x-1|+2\leq\delta+2$. Since $\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{5}\geq\sqrt{5}\geq1$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
|\sqrt{x^2+4}-\sqrt{5}|=\frac{|x-1||x+1|}{\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{5}}\leq\delta(\delta+2).
\end{align*}
Can you go on from here?

Comment: @sranthop This is hard.